# Storing Current Positions of a Series of Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a program that records the current position of bus drivers in a bus route - I have a method which advances a bus route given two inputs:

1) The bus route
2) The current position in that bus route

I would like to store the current positions of all of the bus routes in a single array. Problem is, I'm trying to think of the best way for the program to remember the current position of each of the bus routes. I'm thinking of writing an inner class, where each object corresponds to a bus route and the current position of that bus route - but to me that sounds a little more intense than necessary. This is my current code:

```
class GossipCounter {

        public GossipCounter(int[][] allBusRoutes) {

        }

        public int[][] advanceRoutes(int[][] currentPositions) {

        }

        public int getNext(int[] busRoute, int currentPosition) {

            //input array elm, get next array elm

            int newPosition = currentPosition;

            //if route position is not the last stop
            if (currentPosition < (busRoute.length - 1)) {
                    newPosition = currentPosition + 1;
            } 
            //if route position is the last stop
            else if (currentPosition == (busRoute.length - 1)) {
                    newPosition = 0;
            }

            return busRoute[newPosition];

        }

}
```

So ideally, I would like to invoke the advanceRoutes method on the currentPositions array, but if I were to create an inner class I would replace the int[][] array with a BusRoute[] array where each elm of the array would correspond to a BusRoute object - any other ideas on how I should proceed, however? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Reading this code, I have absolutely no idea of what all the integers are. You say that your code manipulates bus routes, and bus routes have a position. Why don't you have a BusRoute class, with a position field?

Comment: If you plan to add more functions to your application, consider adding several Domain Objects like Route and Bus. If you're using Java, you should think in OOP way.